# get time of when post is submitted php

Tags: php, html, time, timestamp

I have a text box that submits text to an outside file. I am using
     strftime("%I:%M:%S %p"); 
to get the time that it was sent, however, when the browser is refreshed the time changes. How do I make it so that it is the time of when the submit button is clicked and no the local time?

Comment: Use Javascript to intercept the onsubmit event, add a value to the GET/POST data, then submit the data for you?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to store the time to the file so that when you display it content you read back the time as well.

Whether you use the client time or the server time is probably not really important, as long as you take this time when you write to the file and store this time with the data.